# Samsung HLS playback error

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, samsung-mobile

My application use HLS to play video, it works fine on most devices.
When trying to run it on the Samsung Galaxy S3 or the Samsung Galaxy Note 2 I run into problems.

If I have a decent Wifi-connection playback will run without any problems.
When I cap my connection to a rather low bitrate (about 300-400) and wait until after about 10 seconds, when the player switch layer, playback will stop with the following messages :

```
I/avc_utils(1929): found AVC codec config (320 x 180, Baseline-profile level 3.0)
I/ESQueue(1929): DRC : Change Resolution. [720x404] -> [320x180]

E/ACodec(1929): [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] ERROR(0x8000100b)
E/NuPlayer(1929): Received error from audio decoder, aborting playback.

E/NuPlayer(1929): audio track encountered an error (-2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(15859): error (1, -2147483648)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens, and why only on certain Samsung devices? The Galaxy Nexus works fine for example.

Here is an example of how the m3u8 playlist look :

## EXTM3U

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=755803

http://hiddenserver.com/layer_2.m3u8

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=1577112

http://hiddenserver.com/layer_4.m3u8

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=32083

http://hiddenserver.com/layer_5.m3u8

Comment: Could you show the playlist files?

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: Could you show the playlist file for the lowest bandwidth one? Also a sample of the media in that playlist as well would be helpful.

Comment: I also have this problem.. Is there any solution @Slickelito ?

Comment: I think it has to do with how the video is encoded. I tried the same scenario with a sample HLS from apple and couldn't reproduce this error.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The audio codec I use is AAC. Interestingly enough, if I encode all 3 layers with the same audio parameters the audio keeps playing after switching layer, but the videos stop. Have you found out anything about this issue?

Comment: Do you stop the player by yourself when you got the error ?E/MediaPlayer(15859): error (1, -2147483648)

Answer (score 1):

Samsung S3 has the issue not supporting MP3 audio in HLS streams. 
The developer pages do not show clearly enough that mpeg-ts only supports AAC.

I had exactly the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the video is actually encoded with AAC.

Comment: @vipw my bad, I meant the audio is in the form of AAC and now MP3.

Answer (score 0):

For android 4.0.x and 4.1.x the HLS implementation is buggy to say the least. It seems that the audio and video decoder is not reinitialized with the new parameters when the player switches beetween the layers. I tried the same HLS stream for 4.2 and 4.3 and it worked perfectly.

I also checked the debug log from 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3. 4.2 and 4.3 logged "reinitializing decoder" and 4.1 just gave a lot of decoder errors and crashed.

The problem was also eliminated on 4.1 for the audio when I encoded all layers with the same audio parameters. The video however froze.

All of these observations suggests that the decoders are not initialized and that it is infact a bug in the android player.

Answer (score 0):

**E/MediaPlayer(15859): error (1, -2147483648)** means Player got an error from the audio track of the file the server sent.They need to check whether there is a problem to make chunk file on server side.

Therefore this error can be ignore by the player, and the streaming can play smoothly.

```
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int what, int extra) { 
      if (what != 1 || extra != -2147483648) {
               //Show error
      }else {
           //Skip error
      }
}
```